# TFS NuGet Packager task disable pdb generation

Tags: tfs, nuget

In oreder to add pdb files and make nuget package debugable, I just add -Symbol parameter to nuget pack command as shown below.

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj -Symbols
```

[Creating Symbol Package-Microsoft Documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages)

There is a NuGet Pack Task in TFS and It handles nuget packaging.

[image]
[image]

As far as I understood, NuGet Packager generates pdb files by default. 
I would like to learn how to disable/enable this feature on TFS NuGet Packager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually TFS Nuget Packager task will not generate pdb files by default for now. Unless you create a Symbol package which will include the pdb file.
[image]

For the **version 2** of the task there is an option called **Create symbols package** under Pack options

> Specifies that the package contains sources and symbols. When used
>   with a .nuspec file, this creates a regular NuGet package file and
>   the corresponding symbols package.

With this checked, TFS will generate corresponding symbol packages.

[image]

However this feature/Nuget task version is available only on Visual Studio Team Services and not yet available on-premises TFS. Will coming soon in the near future.

---

For your version of Nuget Packager task you could simply add the `-Symbols` parameter in **NuGet Arguments** under Advanced option to enable symbol package. And the generated pdb files will auto add in the symbol package.